# Custom snippet in visual studio - reformat error

Tags: php, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, code-snippets

I am using VS for writing PHP (I use PHP Tools for VS). I try to add three snippets to html, but only one works.

I add snippet php to add  to html code in php file. And it works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>php</Title>
            <Shortcut>php</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for php block</Description>
            <Author>Matjaz</Author>
      <HelpUrl></HelpUrl>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
                <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations><Code Language="html">
<![CDATA[<?php $selected$$end$ ?>
]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

The second snippet is phpecho (I do a lot of echo) and it not works. The snippet is inserted correctly but I get Visual studio error: Could not reformat the document due to line 30. The original format was restored.

```
<Code Language="html">
<![CDATA[<?php echo $selected$$end$; ?>
]]>
            </Code>
```

The third snippet is phpif which works, but I get the same error as for phpecho:

```
<Code Language="html">
<![CDATA[<?php if ($expression$) { ?>
    $selected$$end$
<?php } ?>
]]>
            </Code>
```

I am completely new in writing code snippets, but I am tired writing all that code. (`<?php ?> <?php echo ;?> <?php if (){ ?> <?php } ?>`).

I try to turn off (Tools->Text Editor->PHP->Formatting->General) auto format on ;, }, paste. There are no other options. I use VS 2013.

Is my snippet code bad?

Comment: Im experiencing the same issue have you ever found a resolution to this?

Comment: No I did not. I buy keyboard with custom keys (macros). :)